# Android 1x overdraw on a single ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-xml, android-drawable

I do not understand why here is an overdraw whereas my `SplashActivity` has a layout consisting only from `<ImageView .../>` and with `null` background drawable set for the window.

Here is the code for activity's `onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
}
```

And `activity_splash` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:context=".feature.splash.SplashActivity"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
```

Still, if the overdraw debug mode is on - the image is clearly blue. Why? I can't really understand where the overdraw comes from.

Answer (score 0):

set imageview backroung null like this:-

```
 android:background="null"
```

remove @ from imageview backround tag

Comment: Android resource linking failed
  /home/user/Software_Development/Projects/Android/Work/NLT/PhotoParty2/presentation/src/main/res/layout/activity_splash.xml:2: AAPT: error: 'null' is incompatible with attribute background (attr) reference|color.

Comment: ok then you can try this:- android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: then remove this :-  window.setBackgroundDrawable(null) in your java file

Comment: tell me finally what do you want to do ?

Comment: "then remove this :- window.setBackgroundDrawable(null) in your java file" - the area is still blue after this (overdraw is present)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191901/discussion-between-sandeep-malik-and-andrey-ilyunin).

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly, the solution is to put `window.setBackgroundDrawable(null)` AFTER `setContentView(...)`. After that the overdraw went away.